# Text not displaying below Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, navigation

all. I'm having some more troubles with CSS and HTML. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but my h1 text does not want to appear below my navigation menu bar. The more I try setting pixels, the more it moves, bringing the navigation menu bar with it. I'm very new to all of this, is there anything you guys can suggest for me?

```css
*{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 }
body{ 
 background:url(../images/background.jpg);
 height:100%; 
 width:100%;
 }
#container{
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-left:710px;
 }
.menu{
 list-style:none;
 }
.menu li{
 display:block;
 height:50px;
 width:125px;
 float:left;
 background: rbackground: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 50%, #e1e1e1 51%, #f6f6f6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(51%,#e1e1e1), color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ 

*/
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 line-height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 border-right:1px solid #000;
 font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
 }
.child{
 border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
 border-top-left-radius:50px;
 }
.child1{
 border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
 border-top-right-radius:50px;
 }
.menu li:hover{
 background:background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
color:#FDD017
 }
h1{
 font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
 font-size:72px;
 display:block;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9, 10px -10px 30px #feec85, -20px -20px 40px #ffae34, 20px -40px 50px #ec760c, -20px -60px 60px #cd4606, 0 -80px 70px #973716, 10px -90px 80px #451b0e;
 }
A.class1 {color:black;}
A.class1:link  {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
A.class1:visited {text-decoration: none; color: none;}
A.class1:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: orange;}
A.class1:active {text-decoration: none; color: orange;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head><meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <title>Home</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?  family=Francois+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" />
   <style type="text/css">
   </style>

 </head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="child"><a href="index.html" class="class1">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="about_me/about_me.html" class="class1">ABOUT ME</a></li>
<li><a href="inspiration/inspiration.html" class="class1">INSPIRATION</a></li>
<li class="child1"><a href="contact_me/contact_me.html" class="class1">CONTACT ME</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h1>Welcome to Justin Sanchez's Lair!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
body{ 
    background:url(../images/background.jpg);
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    }
#container{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:710px;
    }
.menu{
    list-style:none;
    }
.menu li{
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    width:125px;
    float:left;
    background: rbackground: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 50%, #e1e1e1 51%, #f6f6f6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(51%,#e1e1e1), color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ 

*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
    }
.child{
    border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
    border-top-left-radius:50px;
    }
.child1{
    border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
    border-top-right-radius:50px;
    }
.menu li:hover{
    background:background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
color:#FDD017
    }
h1{
    font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
    font-size:72px;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9, 10px -10px 30px #feec85, -20px -20px 40px #ffae34, 20px -40px 50px #ec760c, -20px -60px 60px #cd4606, 0 -80px 70px #973716, 10px -90px 80px #451b0e;
    }
A.class1 {color:black;}
A.class1:link  {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
A.class1:visited {text-decoration: none; color: none;}
A.class1:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: orange;}
A.class1:active {text-decoration: none; color: orange;}
```

Comment: I'll Admit, I am confused as to what you want to happen.  It looks like the text is under the navbar according to the "Run Code Snippet".  Could you be more specific as to what you want?

Comment: I'd like the text "Welcome to Justin Sanchez's Lair!" to be properly displayed under the navbar. That's the only problem I'm having. After placing the text, it reads the h1 as directly next to the navbar, leaving it not centered even though that's what I have it as.

Comment: if this old question was solved by a given answer, it should be marked as solved by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want.

```
html:

<div id="container">
<span><!--place menu in a span to align it with h1 tag-->
 <ul class="menu">
<li class="child"><a href="index.html" class="class1">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="about_me/about_me.html" class="class1">ABOUT ME</a></li>
<li><a href="inspiration/inspiration.html" class="class1">INSPIRATION</a></li>
<li class="child1"><a href="contact_me/contact_me.html" class="class1">CONTACT ME</a></li>
</ul>
    </span>
    <div id="spacer"></div><!--used to provide spacing between menu-->


    <span id="title"><!-- enclosed h1 tag to align it below ul list above-->
        <h1>Welcome to Justin Sanchez's Lair!</h1>
    </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
     /*used to place space between menu and h1 text*/
     #spacer{

    height:300px;


}

body{ 
    background:url(../images/background.jpg);
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    }
#container{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:710px;

    }
.menu{
    list-style:none;
    }
.menu li{
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    width:125px;
    float:left;
    background: rbackground: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 50%, #e1e1e1 51%, #f6f6f6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(51%,#e1e1e1), color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ 

*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
    }
.child{
    border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
    border-top-left-radius:50px;
    }
.child1{
    border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
    border-top-right-radius:50px;
    }
.menu li:hover{
    background:background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
color:#FDD017
    }
h1{

    font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
    font-size:72px;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9, 10px -10px 30px #feec85, -20px -20px 40px #ffae34, 20px -40px 50px #ec760c, -20px -60px 60px #cd4606, 0 -80px 70px #973716, 10px -90px 80px #451b0e;
    }
A.class1 {color:black;}
A.class1:link  {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
A.class1:visited {text-decoration: none; color: none;}
A.class1:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: orange;}
A.class1:active {text-decoration: none; color: orange;}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/naruw624/ that's a 404 which I removed in an edit. You will need to update your answer if there is a fiddle for it.

Comment: I'll tidy that up later when I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 }
body{ 
 background:url(../images/background.jpg);
 height:100%; 
 width:100%;
 }
#container {
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
}
#container ul {
   clear:left;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
   text-align:center;
}
#container ul li {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   right:50%;
}
#container ul li a {
   display:block;
   margin:0 0 0 1px;
   padding:3px 10px;
   text-decoration:none;
   line-height:1.3em;
}


.menu{
 list-style:none;
 }
.menu li{
 display:block;
 height:50px;
 width:125px;
 float:left;
 background: rbackground: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 50%, #e1e1e1 51%, #f6f6f6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(51%,#e1e1e1), color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ 

*/
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 line-height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 border-right:1px solid #000;
 font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
 }
.child{
 border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
 border-top-left-radius:50px;
 }
.child1{
 border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
 border-top-right-radius:50px;
 }
.menu li:hover{
 background:background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
color:#FDD017
 }
h1{
 font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
 font-size:72px;
 display:block;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9, 10px -10px 30px #feec85, -20px -20px 40px #ffae34, 20px -40px 50px #ec760c, -20px -60px 60px #cd4606, 0 -80px 70px #973716, 10px -90px 80px #451b0e;
 }
A.class1 {color:black;}
A.class1:link  {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
A.class1:visited {text-decoration: none; color: none;}
A.class1:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: orange;}
A.class1:active {text-decoration: none; color: orange;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head><meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <title>Home</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Francois+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <style type="text/css">
   </style>

 </head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="child"><a href="index.html" class="class1">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="about_me/about_me.html" class="class1">ABOUT ME</a></li>
<li><a href="inspiration/inspiration.html" class="class1">INSPIRATION</a></li>
<li class="child1"><a href="contact_me/contact_me.html" class="class1">CONTACT ME</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<h1>Welcome to Justin Sanchez's Lair!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```